# NTPD not actually setting the time

Tags: archlinux, ntp

NTPD appears to run successfully and poll the time server, however it doesn't actually set the time.

```
# ntpd -d &
ntp engine ready
reply from 83.170.75.28: offset 1348642593.061240 delay 0.035977, next query 9s

# date
Thu Jan 1 10:53:29 BST 1970
```

This is using the latest hf Arch Arm kernel.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Christian You can't work it out because I haven't used a question mark?

Comment: I thought it as a statement that, NTPD is not actually setting the time. That's a statement. But why it's not, is the question :P

Comment: Related: [Why isn't NTPd updating local time?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/3474/3763)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting from `ntpd` [documentation](http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.0/ntpd.htm):

> In case there is no TOY chip or for some reason its time is more than
>   1000s from the server time, ntpd assumes something must be terribly
>   wrong and the only reliable action is for the operator to intervene
>   and set the clock by hand.

Again, quoting from the `ntpd` man page:

> **-s** Set the time immediately at startup if the local clock is off by more than 180 seconds.  Allows for a large time correction, eliminating the need to run rdate(8) before starting.

So a `ntpd -s` in a terminal should be sufficient to fix the problem and let `ntpd` adjust the time normally from there on.

UPDATE: now it should be **`ntpd -g`**

Comment: See also: `ntpdate`.

Comment: I've come here after suffering the same problem. I find that with `ntpd` version 4.2.6p5 the -s option does something different to what is described above (it specifies *Statistics file location*). I think the equivalent option is `-g` but this had no effect for me (it is used without effect by the default sysemd unit). What worked for me was to execute `ntpd uk.pool.ntp.org` prior to starting `ntpd`. To do this I added `ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/ntpdate uk.pool.ntp.org` to the systemd unit file.

Comment: updating the above comment, `ntpdate` is deprecated. I am now using `ntpd -gq`.