# Why isn't NTPd updating local time?

Tags: archlinux, ntp

I'm really happy with my Pi so far, but now that the website I'm developing on it is starting to need the time and date, I thought it was about time to get NTPd working.
So I installed an NTP server onto my Windows machine which acutally has a clock in it, and I got my network switch (which doesn't have an RTC) to successfully update its software clock to this Windows NTPd.
Then I try and get the Pi to update... Not so successful:

```
[root@raspberry ~]# ntpd -ds
listening on 127.0.0.1
ntp engine ready
reply from 192.168.0.2: not synced, next query 655s
^Cntp engine exiting
dispatch_imsg in main: pipe closed
Lost child: child exited
Terminating
[root@raspberry ~]# date
Fri Jan  2 04:01:00 BST 1970
[root@raspberry ~]#
```

So it says that my 192.168.0.2 (my windows box) isn't synced. Can I tell it to ignore this like my network switch must? Why doesn't it update the time?

Note: I can't get the Raspberry Pi to update directly from the internet due to the way my network's set up.

Thanks for any guidance..

Comment: Not sure which ntpd server archlinux have, but see if it has the `-g` argument to allow you to jump the clock. Or see if the ntpdate command is available. Note that normally you'd want to run ntpd as a daemon.

Comment: How long has your Windows machine been running NTP?

Comment: The -s option should be forcing the clock to be set.
@Jivings the NTP machine get shut down every day as it's my general workstation, so the NTP server's never up for more than 16 hours.

Comment: Related: [NTPD not actually setting the time](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/2012/3763)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I managed to solve it. The problem was that the server wasn't fudging its stratum to 0 correctly, so the Pi was seeing the server as a stratum 16 and wouldn't touch it with a barge pole, thus the time wasn't being updated. I managed to fudge the server's stratum to 0 so now the Pi updated off it happily.

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem may be in the Windows machine, not in the Pi/ArchLinux, I suggest to try with working NTP servers. See http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Servers/WebHome for a list. (Or http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/ for a group of servers known as pool.ntp.org)

Comment: As I said, I cannot get the Pi to connect to NTP servers on the internet because of my network configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not support the full NTP stack, but instead just SNTP and is not typically suitable for NTP clients.  You have to change a registry key to enable the W32time SNTP service to emulate the expected behavior of standard NTP protocol.

On the Windows machine, open the Registry Editor (`regedit.exe`), and navigate to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters\Type**. Change the key value from **NT5DS** to **NTP**